# Remap Shortcut in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I am trying to remap the command of running my python source file, which is from the [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run) package to the shortcut cmd+r, which is currently used by the replacement function.

if I type:

```
'cmd-r': 'unbind!'
```

It says the command is not found. So I can unbind it.

Do I need to unbind the command or can I somehow assign the new command without doing all of that stuff.

I found this online to remap another command of another package, just as a scheme of how to remap.

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-j': 'unset!'
```

However I could not figure out how to rewrite that for my purpose. Is there a way to rewrite this for my purpose or is that something different?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unset the keymap, you can simple overwrite it by assigning the name of the run command to it:

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-r': 'Python run: run-f5'
```

The author of this made the command a bit hard to guess, since it's more common to use a slug of the command (e.g. `python-run:run-f5`).

You can get a full list of available commands by running `atom.commands.registeredCommands` in the console.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it still does not work. I copied your code, pressed enter and got the following.
bash: ctrl-r:: command not found
What do I do?

Comment: This sounds like a problem unrelated to the mapping of the shortcut. Were you able to invoke the run command with a the default (or any other) shortcut? What operating system are you using? Do you have bash installed?